# Calling function react to node js error 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

i try to call some register from react front to my node.js back using axios  but i got a 400 error saying:

POST http://localhost:9000/user/register 400 (Bad Request) but i don't see where the issue the data i send to the server.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Here my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Service from "../../services/Service";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Register = () => {

  const user = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  }

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(user);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
  }

  const saveUser = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const  data = {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    };
    Service.signUp(data)
      .then(response => {
        setUserData({
          name: response.data.name,
          email: response.data.email,
          password: response.data.password
        })
        setSubmitted(true);
        console.log(userData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  const newUser = () => {
    setUserData(user);
    setSubmitted(false);
  }

  const { name, email, password, confirmPassword } = userData;

  const btn = name === '' || email === '' || password === '' || password !== confirmPassword
  ? <button disabled>Inscription</button> : <button>Inscription</button>

  // gestion erreurs
  const errorMsg = error !== '' && <span>{error.message}</span>

  return (

    <div className="signUpLoginBox">
      <div className="slContainer">
        <div className="">
          <div className="formContent">
            <form onSubmit={saveUser}>

              {errorMsg}

              <h2>Inscription</h2>
              <div className="inputBox">
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={handleChange} value={name} autoComplete="off"  />
                <label htmlFor="pseudo">Name</label>
              </div>

              <div className="inputBox">
                <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} value={email} autoComplete="off" required />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              </div>

              <div className="inputBox">
                <input type="password" id="password" onChange={handleChange} value={password} autoComplete="off" required />
                <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
              </div>
              <div className="inputBox">
                <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" onChange={handleChange} value={confirmPassword} autoComplete="off" required />
                <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirmez le mot de passe</label>
              </div>

              {btn}

            </form>
            <div className="linkContainer">
              <Link className="simpleLink" to="/login">Déjà inscrit? Connectez-vous </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register
```

my auth file node.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require('./validation');


router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  //LETS VALIDATE THE DATA BEFORE WE A USER
  const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Checking if the user is already in the database
  const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
  if(emailExist) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists');

  //Hash passwords
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  //Create a new user
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
  });
  try{
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send( {user: user._id});
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

and then in my app.js (node) is like:

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const testAPIRouter = require('./routes/testAPI');
const disneyCharacterRouter = require('./routes/disneyCharacter');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();


dotenv.config();

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () =>
    console.log('connected to DB!')
);


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//Route Middleware
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/testAPI', testAPIRouter);
app.use('/disneyCharacter', disneyCharacterRouter);
app.use('/user', authRoute);
app.use('/posts', postRoute);
```

the Validation.js (node):

```
 const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

//Register Validation
const registerValidation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string()
      .min(6)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.string()
      .min(6)
      .required()
      .email(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .min(6)
      .required()
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};
```

the http-common.js file:

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9000",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

service.js :

```
 import http from "../http-common";

    const signUp = data => {
      return http.post('/user/register', data);
    };
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: wats the logs on node server console. do u get errors ?

Comment: wats the network response. In your code, there are few 400 being sent and some error message along with it. That should tell you what went wrong. Basically, you have coded to 400 and you are wondering why it is 400 ??

Comment: the log it's just : POST /user/register 400 1.358 ms - 33.

Comment: okay so i change:   const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message); to res.status(201) and the server say 201 error so i think the issue is with my req.body. Thanks i will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i find a solution i don't really know why but my function handleChange:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
  }
```

wasn't do nothing, so i change it like that:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');


  const saveUser = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const  data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/user/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
```

you can write like that to keep the axios version:

```
  const saveUser = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const  data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    Service.signUp(JSON.stringify(data))
      .then(
        setSubmitted(true),
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      )
      .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

and the form :

```
      <div className="inputBox">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} autoComplete="off"  />
        <label htmlFor="pseudo">Name</label>
      </div>

      <div className="inputBox">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} autoComplete="off" required />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      </div>

      <div className="inputBox">
        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} autoComplete="off" required />
        <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
      </div>
      <div className="inputBox">
        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" onChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} value={confirmPassword} autoComplete="off" required />
        <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirmez le mot de passe</label>
      </div>
```

and it's work.